# No Message error when submitting a post request

Tags: php, laravel, message

I'm trying to post data to a database using a post request. I'm also using data from an Input in a previous page.

I.e

- User visits profile & adds info into a form
- The form data is posted to a controller and then create view returned with input data
- The form in the create view is pre-populated by the previous data (from controller)
- the user should be able to submit the form, but it throws no message error

I've noticed the URL is /prebook opposed to /booking/create (this is due to the profile page passing data into a controller and it outputting.

Any ideas?

Profile Controller

```
public function prebook() {

        $date = Input::get('query', '01/01/2010');
        $guests = Input::get('guests', '2');
        $restaurant = Input::get('restaurantID', '2');
        $restaurantName = Input::get('restaurantName', '2');
        $time = Input::get('timeFrom', '2');

        return view('userbookings.create')->with('date', $date)
                                          ->with('guests', $guests)
                                          ->with('restaurant', $restaurant)
                                          ->with('restaurantName', $restaurantName)
                                          ->with('time', $time);

}
```

Post form code

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'user.bookings.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
    @include('userbookings.form')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Create Form (example input field)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Party Size:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input required type="number" class="form-control" value="{{$guests}}" id='partySize' name='PartySize'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Store Method in Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
      'date' => 'required',
      'timeFrom' => 'required',
      'timeTo' => 'required',
      'partySize' => 'required',
      'status' => 'required',
      'comments' => 'required',
    ]);

    Booking::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('user.bookings.index')
                     ->with('success','Booking created successfully');
}
```

Migration Code:

```
  Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        **$table->string('date');**
        **$table->string('timeFrom');**
        $table->string('timeTo');
        **$table->string('partySize');**
        $table->string('status');
        $table->text('comments');
        **$table->text('businessID');**
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: do you mean that you want to retrieve your data from prebook function into store function? or do you want to retrieve your data from your view?

Comment: Im trying to use the data from Prebook to be stored in the Store function. 

So far..the data populates the form for the store function from the prebook data. but when I submit the form, it says no message.

end goal is to submit the form with the prebook data inside of it.

Comment: can you put your migration code that you want to store your data? I want to make sure how do you want to store the prebook data and booking data

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Its added now, the ones in with star's are the ones that are prepopulated by the form on the profile.

Comment: Please also note: The prebook data is coming from a view with a form, which is then fed into the store form (successfully). so its just posting the store form is the issue.

Comment: why don't u store the data directly? u are using 1 table database but you send the value into the view then the view call the controller again to submit the value..